# What can you do to boost Fps in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner in python and pygame and I have been making a 2D top-down game (it is very similar to the legend of Zelda) I only have the made the start screen and the first screen where you can run around, but the fps is in the low 20's and I was wondering what I could do to boost it. I have no clue what to do at all.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('Music/Start.mp3')
click = pygame.mixer.Sound('Music/Sounds/Click.wav')
pygame.mixer_music.play()

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = "True"

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png')]
idle = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_idle.png')]

fullheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Heart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Heart.png')]
halfheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/HalfHeart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/HalfHeart.png')]
noheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/NoHeart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/NoHeart.png')]

bg = pygame.image.load('Ground/BG.png')
startscreen = pygame.image.load('Wraith/StartScreen.png')

sword = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Sword.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Sword.png')]
shield = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Shield.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Shield.png')]

redberries = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/RedBerries.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/RedBerries.png')]
blueberries = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/BlueBerries.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/BlueBerries.png')]

inventory = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Inventory.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Inventory.png')]
slots = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Slots.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Slots.png')]
notequipped = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/NotEquiped.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/NotEquiped.png')]

swordslot = [pygame.image.load("Wraith/SwordSlot.png"), pygame.image.load("Wraith/SwordSlot.png")]
shieldslot = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/ShieldSlot.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/ShieldSlot.png')]

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 18)
newfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Ariel', 150)


new = newfont.render("NEW GAME", True, black)
settings = newfont.render("SETTINGS", True, black)
quit = newfont.render("QUIT", True, black)

WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080

playerx = 900
playery = 485

mouseposx = 175
mouseposy = 185

startx = 175
starty = 185

slotx = 175
sloty = 185

detectx = 0
detecty = 0

walkCount = 0
icon = 1
inv = 0

move_left = False
move_right = False
move_up = False
move_down = False

arangeinventory = False
accessinventory = False
mousepos = False

Heath = 6
ability1 = "Sword"
ability2 = "Shield"
ability3 = "Red Berries"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

game = True
startarea = True
slotloop = False


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global icon
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    screen.blit(update_fps(), (1900, 0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 60:
        walkCount = 0

    if move_right == False and move_left == False:
        screen.blit(idle[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1
    if move_right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1
    if move_left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1

    if Heath == 6:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 5:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 4:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 3:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 2:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 1:
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))

    if ability1 == "Sword":
        screen.blit(sword[icon], (1728, 888))
    if ability2 == "Shield":
        screen.blit(shield[icon], (1792, 760))
    if ability3 == "Red Berries":
        screen.blit(redberries[icon], (1601, 952))
    elif ability3 == "Blue Berries":
        screen.blit(blueberries[icon], (1601, 952))

    if accessinventory:
        arangeinventory = True
        screen.blit(inventory[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (175, 185))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (769, 185))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (1263, 185))
        screen.blit(swordslot[icon], (slotx, sloty))
        screen.blit(shieldslot[icon], (769, 185))
    pygame.display.update()


def update_fps():
    fps = str(int(clock.get_fps()))
    fps_text = font.render(fps, 1, white)
    return fps_text


while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

        while startarea:
            screen.blit(startscreen, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(new, (650, 488))
            screen.blit(quit, (790, 888))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    startx, starty = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if startx >= 624 and startx <= 1257 and starty >= 855 and starty <= 1028:
                        click.play()
                        sys.exit()
                    elif startx >= 624 and startx <= 1257 and starty >= 445 and starty <= 618:
                        click.play()
                        startarea = False
                    else:
                        None
            pygame.display.update()

        if event.type == pygame.K_UP and playery > 0: playery -= 5
        if event.type == pygame.K_DOWN and playery < 1920 - 64: playery += 5
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT and playerx > 0: playerx -= 5
        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT and playerx < 1080 - 64: playerx += 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = True
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = True
                move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_i:
                inv += 1

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = False

    if (inv % 2) == 0:
        arangeinventory = False
        accessinventory = False
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    else:
        arangeinventory = True
        accessinventory = True
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    if playery > 0:
        playery -= 10
    if playery < 1060 - 50:
        playery += 10
    if playerx > 0:
        playerx -= 10
    if playerx < 1920 - 50:
        playerx += 10

    if move_left:
        playerx -= 10
    if move_right:
        playerx += 10
    if move_up:
        playery -= 10
    if move_down:
        playery += 10

    redrawGameWindow()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: The first place to start in diagnosing performance issues is typically to run a sampling profiler -- though if you haven't run other games written in pygame to get a baseline for how they behave on your hardware+software stack, that's always a good place to start, just to make sure your code is the right place to start debugging (as opposed to graphics drivers or something else).

Comment: Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) to ensure that all _Surfaces_ will have the same pixel format as the display Surface. This gives a performance gain, when a Surface is _blit_ to the display _Surface_.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is generally a bit too broadly scoped to be on-topic on Stack Overflow -- we favor narrow, specific questions about well-defined problems, with only the shortest possible code that successfully reproduces the problem included.

Comment: Insofar as you have _working_ code, if you're willing to accept general comments and not only ones that are performance related, you might review our sister site [codereview.se] and see if it's a fit for your needs. [A Guide to Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777) might be a starting point to evaluate how the rules for what's accepted on each of the two sites differ.

Comment: Avoid calling `pygame.mixer.music.unpause()`/`pygame.mixer.music.pause()` in every frame.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is *not* executed is always fastest.

As Rabbid76 suggests, you're pausing/unpausing the music every frame, this is not necessary.  Trigger it with the KEYUP event:

```
        if event.key == pygame.K_i:
            inv += 1
            if ( inv % 2 ):
                arangeinventory = False
                accessinventory = False
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            else:
                arangeinventory = True
                accessinventory = True
                pygame.mixer.music.pause()
```

When you blit an image, PyGame needs to convert it to match the same format of the target surface.  You can do this once, or do it every time.  Personally I like once:

```
walkRight = [ pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png').convert_alpha(), 
              pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png').convert_alpha(),
              ...
```

Don't forget to `convert()` your background and health-bar images too.

There's a lot of code in this animation-loading, and why load in repeated frames you already have?  Currently you're loading and storing the same frame-set four times.  Sure it's not slowing down the execution during play, but it's using resources unnecessarily.  Only load in the images you need.  Cycle at 12, not 48.

```
walkRight = []
for i in range( 1, 13 ):
    filename = 'Wraith_%02d.png' % ( i )
    filename = os.path.join( 'Wraith', filename ) 
    frame = pygame.image.load( filename ).convert_alpha()
    walkRight.append( frame )
 ### etc. for left and idle.
```

To draw the health-bar, you're doing 3 separate `blit()`s.  Perhaps you could pre-create a list of health-bar images, and just blit `health_images[ health ]` to the screen once.

You don't seem to use a lot of `else` logic.  This has a very minimal impact on the execution time, but if inside a tight-loop it's doing comparison checks for no reason. For example consider your directional code:

```
if move_right == False and move_left == False:
    screen.blit(idle[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
    walkCount += 1
if move_right:
    screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
    walkCount += 1
if move_left:
    screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
    walkCount += 1
```

Can the player walk both left & right at the same time?  If we already checked the player is not moving, why test again?

```
if move_right:
    screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (playerx, playery))  # go right
elif move_left:
    screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (playerx, playery))   # go left
else:
    screen.blit(idle[walkCount], (playerx, playery))       # idle
walkCount += 1
```

Similarly with the event logic - a single event can't have more than 1 key value, use if/elif/else so less checks are made.  Once the result is made, no futher `if`s are tested.

```
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            move_left = True
            move_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            move_right = True
            move_left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            move_up = True
        ... etc.
```